# Visual Studio Extend IDE - the Exception Assistant

Tags: visual-studio, exception, vs-extensibility

The aim here is to incorporate [StackOverflow](http://www.Stackoverflow.com) popular answers into Visual Studio's Exception Assistant.

---

I have trawled the web without luck, the only information I could find about *customizing the Exception Assistant* is this link below that shows how to add links to the "Troubleshooting Tip" area:

http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/07/exception-occurred-get-troubleshooting-tips-from-your-favorites-blogs/

> My question is it possible to tap into other areas of the Exception Assistant such
>   as: Actions, View Details?

I also found that adding links to Troubleshooting Tip area is limited: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/3b045e98-081c-4540-b27b-3121245e53ee,

---

I have posted the idea on Microsoft's Visual Studio suggestion site, vote for it if you like the idea:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2847295-exception-assistant-exstensibility-to-tap-into-t

---

**UPDATE (May 2015):**

Microsoft is doing something similar with Developer Assistant, just need to tap into the error assistant with StackOverflow in the same way: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1166718-a2d9-4a48-a5fd-504ff4ad1b65

Comment: Gave you three votes for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to extend it as well. Doing a bit of research it seems its not possible.

> Unfortunately this is not possible.  We will consider this when we do
>   our future planning for the Visual Studio debugger though.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Brad Sullivan - Program Manager - Visual Studio Debugger (source http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3b045e98-081c-4540-b27b-3121245e53ee/)

Comment: Thanks @Tom, obviously when it becomes available I'll extend it and integrate [so] into the VS Exception Assistant...

Comment: Haha, that was exactly what I wanted to do for my 10% time at work. I have a few other possible ways of doing it. Up for teaming up some time?

Comment: Yeah for sure, lets keep monitoring and jump on it when  it becomes available :-)

Comment: I really hate the way the closed source commercial IDE deals with these type issues. With Eclipse this type of customization is so easy!!

Comment: @MasudRahman, I would love to see a version of this idea in Eclipse as well as other IDE's beside .Net and Java one's. A language neutral polymorphic implementation that could be ported to all/most languages implemented via abstract functions so that a core API could evolve would be ideal.

Comment: Actually, I tried to do something in the pro-active mode of SurfClipse. Once an exception encounters, it automatically searches for relevant web pages and gathers within the IDE. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTIkFYrnllY

Comment: I just saw this now @MasudRahman - WOW man!! That is really impressive. Well done. Any chance you will make it open source?

Comment: @JeremyThompson, although the web service is off due to its costs, you can fork the Eclipse client from here : https://github.com/masud-technope/SurfClipseClientGH

Answer (score 0):

I've started the project, its very much WIP and needs contributors.

## Contribute to [GitHub Stackoverflow Exception Assistant](https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/StackoverflowExceptionAssistant):

[image]