# Force Visual Studio to preserve exponent shorthand notation eg "1e6"

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, formatting

I'm working with Ticks a lot at the moment and when setting a timespan/similar, I find the shorthand exponent notation `3e6` far more easy to read at a glance than `3000000`

VS converts to the long form as soon as it tidies up the line.

Is there any way to turn off the editor feature which reformats this?

As requested, a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please add a screenshot to show me before and after 'VS understand 1e6 - `it simply converts it to 1000000 when it tidies up the line`'

Comment: +1 I added a comment, I think you can only do it using a string for "WhatUWant"

Answer (score 1):

The Timespan.Ticks is a Long so I'm not to sure what you mean by 'VS converts to the long as soon as it tidies up' - its always a long.

Hence you'd either need to use a datatype that supports exponent notation like a double or you could use this method: ts.Ticks.ToString("0.###E+0"). I think the latter method with the QuickWatch window would be the best approach.

Edit: After reading your comments, I need to see a screenshot, here's what my IDE displays:

[image]

Comment: I'm not talking about the data type at all - just the number format eg 1000000 = 1e6. I'd prefer to see 1e6 in my code instead of 1000000. VS understand 1e6 - it simply converts it to 1000000 when it tidies up the line - try it.

Comment: I can, of course, format it/output it any way I like before display to the user. This is purely to make my life easier

Comment: I've added a screenshot - not sure how much clearer I can make it

Comment: Dim whatIWant As String = "1e6"                                        
Dim whatIGet = Decimal.Parse(whatIWant, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);

Comment: Thanks for trying to give me an alternative, but I wouldn't do that ever. It's hacky, prone to run-time errors (typos in number) and requires additional processing - All I want is to tweak the editor's auto-formatting, not change the fundamental code.

Comment: I wouldn't do it either - I'd use the QuickWatch window technique. You would think with the IDE switch from Winforms to WPF in 2010 would allow for these tweaks we want. Perhaps you could put a bounty on this question, but I don't think its possible and bounties I've put on the VS Extension questions came up blank and lost me points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816556/visual-studio-extend-ide-the-exception-assistant

Comment: Whoops - I forgot to +91 your answer for a workaround. Sorry. Fixed now